# How to write to external SD card (Micro SD) when tablet has multiple external directories

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-external-storage

I'm getting a permission denied error when attempting to write to an external Micro SD card that has been put inside the tablet.  I've failed trying to save a file to the Micro SD using hard coded values for the path and when also using what is returned from getExternalStorageDirectory().

Here are the things that I've noted while testing this out.

- The path to my Micro SD card is /storage/sdcard1/ (myself and utility verified)
- /storage/emulated/0 is returned from Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
- The path /storage/sdcard1/ is valid as I can read from it
- Permissions set (android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) is in Manifest.xml
- The permission tag is in the correct location of Manifest.xml (outside of application tag)
- I can write to /storage/scard0/ hard-coded and by getExternalStorageDirectory()

The other threads say to not hard-code when writing to the SD card and use what is returned from getExternalStorageDirectory(), but that doesn't return my external micro sd card.

I get this when I try to write to it.

Java.io.FileNotFound: /storage/scard1/Report Summary.csv : open failed: EACCESS (permission denied)

In this situation what can I do to write to the micro sd card?

Comment: On Android 4.4+, you do not have arbitrary access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). If the device itself seems to be recognizing the card, use the [Storage Access Framework](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/03/storage-access-framework-faq.html) to allow the user to choose or create files where the user wants, including that card.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare 
That really helped.  I'm going to just use what is returned from the getExternalStorageDirectory() as it is stated in your reference:

"Specifically getExternalFilesDirs() and getExternalCacheDirs() (note the plural form) will not only return directories that we can use on “real” external storage, but also will return directories that we can use on any available and supported removable media"

Comment: Another interesting this is that in Lollipop, there is a setting to change the "default write disk" between 'USB storage' and 'SD Card'.  I wonder what 'SD card' is referring to?

Comment: That is not part of Android. It must be specific to your hardware.

Comment: Would there be any reason why you would be able to write a file to what is returned by getExternalStorageDirectory and not be able to create a folder?  I get read-only file system error when I try.  I just don't want to have files in the root, but rather grouped in folders

Comment: I was under the impression that you could create subdirectories under the `getExternalFilesDirs()` locations, but I haven't tried it. You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.

Comment: I have the writing of the folders and files working for the internal non-removable storage now.  I'll look into the removable SD card at another time.  Thanks again for the help.